# CSS flex-grow not making columns height match

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, flexbox

I have 3 columns that are displayed flex. They have different text in them so naturally, their heights don't match. I'm trying to use `flex-grow: 1;` to have them match each other's height but this does not seem to be working for me. Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
.container {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.container .item {
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 25px;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

https://codepen.io/albert-anthony4962/pen/OJpvZyO

Comment: Use align-items: stretch. You can have a look here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#align-items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `align-self: stretch;` on `.item`;

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing `align-items` from `.container`?

Comment: That was it, thanks for helping me figure it out